# MatToolTip is not working properly in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using MatToolTip in one of my lazy loaded modules, and I am not getting any error, but all the tooltip texts ( that are provided to the matTooltip property ) are shown on the left bottom corner of the screen and not on the element where the tooltip is supposed to show.

It was working just fine when I was using Angular 9, but now I moved Annular 11 and the texts are not in their appropriate positions

Here is the html code where I am using matToolTip

```
 <div
      mat-raised-button
      matTooltip="No changes made"
      [matTooltipDisabled]="active"
      [class.save-active]="active"
      (click)="save.emit()"
      class="save"
 >
  {{ text }}
 </div>
```

This is how my SharedModule looks like

```
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

@NgModule({
...,
 imports: [..., MatTooltipModule,],
 exports: [...,  MatTooltipModule,],
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

and this is how my AppModule looks like

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@NgModule({
...,
 imports: [
     ...,     
     BrowserModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule
 ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Anyone has an idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the Material CSS inside your styles.css like this:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: check the new answer :)

Comment: does it display something in the console ?

Comment: This is the only thing that might be related 

GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?l=dataLayer net::ERR_ABORTED 500

Comment: So you want to show a tooltip for a button but its showing on the bottom of the page, right?
Have you checked if all the html tags are properly closed and you are using all the properties for that MatToolTip? Maybe inside the terminal you are having an error, try to re-compile

Comment: Yes but not for a button only, for many different elements. And all of them are showing on the bottom of the screen


I will add something to the question thet might be helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225992/discussion-between-pau-and-ahmed-saeed).